# does the equation $f_1^3 + f_2^2 = f_3^4$ have a solution in homogeneous polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

> Does there exist three non-zero homogeneous polynomials in $k[x,y]$, $k$ an algebraically closed field (ADDED: of characteristic 0), $f_1$ of degree 4, $f_2$ of degree 6, and $f_3$ of degree 3, and such that $f_1$ and $f_2$ do not have a common denominator of degree 2, that satisfy the equation
>   $$
> f_1^3 + f_2^2 = f_3^4\ ?
> $$

This elementary problem arises from the following question: does there exist a rational elliptic surface with a discriminant divisor that consists of three distinct points with multiplicity 4 --- which amounts to three singular fibres of the Kodaira $I_4$ type --- see Heckman-Looijenga, [The moduli space of rational elliptic surfaces](https://www.math.ru.nl/~heckman/Heck_14.pdf).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? In what context did you find this polynomial? Also, how many variables should the polynomials have?

Comment: @Servaes this problem can be reformulated as a problem about intersections of certain subvarieties of the linear system $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(12)|$, and I tried to show that the intersection is non-empty by dimension count, which did not work. I believe if the solution exists it should perhaps be possible to arrive at it using elementary methods, however, after playing with $f_i$ consisting of a small number of terms (such as binomials) I am at a loss.

Comment: Perhaps you already know of them, but there exist three polynomials satisfying all your requirements except for the degrees, namely $f'_1=x^8+14x^4y^4+y^8$ of degree 8, $f'_2=i(x^{12}-33x^8y^4-33x^4y^8+y^{12})$ of degree 12 and $f'_3=(108)^{1/4} xy(x^4-y^4)$ of degree 6. They are described e.g. in page 61 of [this book](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/Quintic/quintic.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a first draft of an answer; it might contain errors, I will double check and clean it up soon, perhaps tomorrow. It shows that no such polynomials exist if $\operatorname{char}k\neq2,3$.

---

If such homogeneous polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3\in k[x,y]$ exist, then
$$f_1^3=f_3^4-f_2^2=(f_3^2+f_2)(f_3^2-f_2).\tag{1}$$

The square of the $\gcd$ of the factors on the right hand side divides $f_1^3$, so $\gcd(f_3^2+f_2,f_3^2-f_2)=h^3$ for some monic $h\in k[x,y]$. Then $h^3\mid2f_2$ and $h^6\mid f_1^3$, so $h^2\mid f_1$. From your requirement that $f_1$ and $f_2$ do not have a quadratic common divisor it follows that $h=1$. It also follows that $\gcd(f_2,f_3)=1$.

It now follows from $(1)$ that both $f_3^2+f_2$ and $f_3^2-f_2$ are coprime cubes. Let $h_1,h_2\in k[x,y]$ be such that
$$h_1^3=f_3^2+f_2
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
h_2^3=f_3^2-f_2.$$
Comparing degrees in identity $(1)$ and in the above shows that $\deg h_1=\deg h_2=2$. Then
$$2f_2=(f_3^2+f_2)-(f_3^2-f_2)
=h_1^3-h_2^3=(h_1-h_2)(h_1^2+h_1h_2+h_2^2),$$
$$2f_3^2=(f_3^2+f_2)+(f_3^2+f_2)
=h_1^3+h_2^3=(h_1+h_2)(h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2).\tag{2}$$

Of course $\gcd(h_1+h_2,h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2)$ divides
$$(h_1-2h_2)(h_1+h_2)-(h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2)=-3h_2^2,$$
$$(h_2-2h_1)(h_1+h_2)-(h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2)=-3h_1^2,$$
and because $\operatorname{char}{k}\neq3$ it follows that the $\gcd$ divides both $h_1^2$ and $h_2^2$, hence it also divides
$$f_2=\tfrac12(h_1^3-h_2^3)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad f_3^2=\tfrac12(h_1^3+h_2^3),$$
and so it equals $1$. Then both factors of $2f_3^2$ at the right hand side of $(2)$ are squares, meaning that there exist coprime $u,v\in k[x,y]$ such that
$$h_1+h_2=u^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2=v^2.$$
Then $u$ and $v$ are again homogeneous and $u^2v^2=2f_3^2$, so $\deg u+\deg v=3$. Then
$$\deg u^2\leq\max\{\deg h_1,\deg h_2\}=2
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\deg v^2\leq\max\{2\deg h_1,2\deg h_2\}=4,$$
and from $\deg u+\deg v=3$ it follows that $\deg u=1$ and $\deg v=2$. A bit of algebra shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
3h_1h_2
&=&(h_1+h_2)^2-(h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2)\\
&=&u^4-v^2\\
&=&(u^2+v)(u^2-v),\\
3(h_1^2+h_1h_2+h_2^2)
&=&3(h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2)+6h_1h_2\\
&=&3v^2+2(u^2+v)(u^2-v)\\
&=&2u^4+v^2,\\
3(h_1-h_2)^2
&=&3(h_1+h_2)^2-6h_1h_2\\
&=&3u^4-4(u^2+v)(u^2-v)\\
&=&-u^4+4v^2\\
&=&(2v+u^2)(2v-u^2).
\end{eqnarray*}
In the latter we see that $2v+u^2$ and $2v-u^2$ are coprime because $u$ and $v$ are, and so both are squares. Let $s,t\in k[x,y]$ be such that
$$s^2=2v+u^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad t^2=2v-u^2.$$
Note that both $s$ and $t$ are linear and homogeneous. Then
$$4v=s^2+t^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 2u^2=s^2-t^2.$$
Now we can express $f_2^2$ and $f_3^4$ in terms of $s$ and $t$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{12}f_3^4
&=&2^{10}u^4v^4=(s^2-t^2)^2(s^2+t^2)^4\\
&=&t^{12}+2s^2t^{10}-s^4t^8-8s^6t^6-s^8t^4+2s^{10}t^2+s^{12},\\
2^{10}3^3f_2^2
&=&2^{10}3^3(h_1-h_2)^2(h_1^2+h_1h_2+h_2^2)^2\\
&=&2^{10}(2v+u^2)(2v-u^2)(2u^4+v^2)^2\\
&=&(4v+2u^2)(4v-2u^2)(2^5u^4+2^4v^2)^2\\
&=&4s^2t^2(2^3(s^2-t^2)^2+(s^2+t^2)^2)^2\\
&=&4s^2t^2(9s^4-15s^2t^2+9t^4)^2\\
&=&36(9s^2t^{10}-30s^4t^8+43s^6t^6-30s^8t^4+9s^{10}t^2),
\end{eqnarray*}
and this allows us to also express $f_1^3$ in terms of $s$ and $t$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
3(16f_1)^3
&=&3(2^{12}f_3^4)-2^4(2^83^1f_2^2)\\
&=&3t^{12}-138s^2t^{10}+477s^4t^8-712s^6t^6+477s^8t^4-138s^{10}t^2+3s^{12}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is a palindromic polynomial in $s^2$ and $t^2$, which means that
\begin{eqnarray*}
(16f_1)^3&=&
t^{12}-43s^2t^{10}+159s^4t^8-238s^6t^6+159s^8t^4-43s^{10}t^2+s^{12}\\
&=&(st)^6q\left(\left(\tfrac ts\right)^2+\left(\tfrac st\right)^2\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
for some cubic $q\in k[X]$. Then comparing degrees shows that $q$ must be the cube of a linear polynomial. A bit more algebra shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
q(z+z^{-1})
&=&z^3-43z^2+159z-238+159z^{-1}-43z^{-2}+z^{-3}\\
&=&\left(z+z^{-1}\right)^3-43\left(z+z^{-1}\right)^2+156\left(z-z^{-1}\right)-152.
\end{eqnarray*}
But it is clear that
$$q=X^3-43X^2+156X-152,$$
is not a cube in $k[X]$. We have finally reached a contradiction; no such polynomials exist.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there is no solution, though I don't know of an elementary way to show it.

In terms of the original problem, it turns out that it is impossible to have a rational elliptic surface with three $I_4$ fibres by Shioda-Tate formula: this forumla computes the rank of the group of rational sections as $\rho - 2 - \sum N_i$ where $N_i$ is the number of irreducible components of the fibres. In our case we have three fibres which are cycles of 4 ratinal curves, each contributing 4 to  the Euler characteristic of the fibration, hence $\rho = 10$, and also $N_1=N_2=N_3=3$, so the expression given by the formula is negative, which is impossible.

The positive solution to the posted question would imply the existence of such an elliptic surface (see Heckmann-Looijenga, Section~2).